# Change .text() of a div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot get jquery to change the text of a div. I have gotten the code to work on jfiddle but on the live site it is not being detected. I have even tried to add the function to (document) click so it ensure the function runs.

```
$(document).click( function () {
var ptime = $('#vaptimelineblock0').text();
    if (ptime == "07:00 PM") {
        $('#vaptimelineblock0').text("7:15 pm");
    }
});
```

The live project is located

http://ecofreshdrycleaners.com/component/vikappointments/?view=servicesearch&id_ser=2

EDIT:
Here is the jfiddle working

https://jsfiddle.net/cts5bfud/

Comment: Fix the script errors shown in the browser console *`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`*

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. Where's your jsFiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cts5bfud/

Comment: Seeing a working jsfiddle isn't very helpful. You'll have to edit the fiddle so that it replicates the problem you're having with the actual project.

Comment: ... If i knew how to replicate the problem i would know how to fix the problem, this is why i am looking for help and posted the live site so dont down vote me just because you cant help.

Comment: Are you sure that in your project ptime is exactly equals to "07:00 PM" ( case sensitive) ?

Comment: yea i copy pasted the html from the page into the jsfiddle. I think this problem is about how the text is generated dynamically that jquery doesnt see it as normal html... maybe something wierd like that?

Comment: Until you fix the existing unrelated error your code above may not even be parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said in comments you need to fix error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Cause of that error is this code:

```
document.getElementById("couponkey").value=document.getElementById("couponcode").innerHTML;
```

You don't have element with id 'couponkey'.
Remove this code and it all works fine (or set element with that id properly).

Comment: Thank you, I removed it and now i am getting an error on every document click in the console stating $ is not a function. I would assume this is some sort of jquery conflict

Comment: yes, try using `jQuery` instead of `$` and check this also https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
$('#vaptimelineblock0').html("7:15 pm");
```

Comment: Why would `.html()` work any better than `.text()`?

Comment: .text() is read-only. for example if you put a word in a  div or in span, .text() will return the word. But what .text('word') should do ?

Comment: That's totally wrong. `.text()` is not read-only. Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/). `.text('word')` would set the text content of a node to `word`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cts5bfud/   see it works just fine here